# Bootstrap nav rollover not working when page is scrolled down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.webxury.net/datacenter/index.html

If you go to the link above you will see the navigation at the top is white text on black, and orange text when the mouse is hovered - however if you scroll down to to the bottom of the page the rollover on the nav stops working.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: I just tried from 3 different browsers on 2 different computers. I see no issue with this.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be fine to me. What browser are you using?

[image: ss]

Comment: Thanks for checking it out, im using Chrome on Windows

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly for me on Chrome, Windows 7.

`CTRL + F5` will do the trick. I guess the page is cached and that's why you don't see the changes. With this, you will refresh the cache and it will work.